# ADO.NET и постраничный вывод без SQL Limit(offset) в Transbase

Tags: sql, limit

Добрый день, есть одна БД(Transbase), к которой подключаюсь через ADO.NET.
Эта БД не поддерживает SQL оператор **LIMIT**, но мне нужно организовать постраничный вывод(выборка заданного кол-тва row-s с возможностью задать начального offset-а для таблицы), поскольку таблицы в этой БД занимают гигабайты, и подгружать всю таблицу за раз не вариант. 
Эта БД поддерживает курсоры, и можно попробовать использовать offset в коде, и итератор. Но если к примеру пользователь захочет посмотреть столбцы, начиная с 100-тысячного, приходится крутить цикл, пока не дойдет до этого офсета, что отнимает процессорное время, и создает не нужные нагрузки.

*Как можно еще организовать постраничный вывод из БД, без SQL оператора LIMIT?*

Comment: с какой СУБД работаете?

Comment: @Ruslan_K Transbase.

Comment: [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769655/5045688) пишут, что можно использовать `FIRST`. Transbase вроде поддерживает оконные функции; если это действительно так, то offset можно сделать с помощью `row_number() over`.

Comment: Да, `FIRST` бесполезен в данном контексте.
Transbase действительно поддерживает оконные функции(*WindowFunction*), но я не нашел способа как это сделать. В [документации](https://yadi.sk/i/d8T3cLZxuEG8V) пишется, что они применимы только для оператора SELECT.

Comment: Вообще в Transbase оконные функции не поддерживают `row_number()`, только:

`window_function_name ::= { AVG | COUNT |
DENSE_RANK | MAX |
MIN | RANK | SUM }`

Comment: В общем, как я понял, RANK и DENSE_RANK функции, это все равно что функция `row_number`, только с проверкой на уникальность.
Только я не пойму, как ее использовать в качестве ограничителя выборки?
К примеру вот такая выборка: 

`SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY column_1, column_2, column_3) AS RANK_OFFSET
FROM TABLE_USER.SOME_TABLE_1`

но я не могу использовать RANK_OFFSET в WHERE, как мне тогда его ограничить?

Comment: В чем необходимость использования именно составного ключа? может тогда добавить легковесное числовое поле только для лимитации выборки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я разобрался как это можно сделать:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT column_1, 
           column_2, 
           column_3, 
           RANK() OVER(ORDER BY column_1, column_2, column_3) AS RANK_OFFSET 
    FROM USER_NAME.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE RANK_OFFSET BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

Но, тут есть пару проблем:

1. Поскольку оконные функции выполняются последними, нет возможности использовать результат их работы в `WHERE` где была использована оконная функция, и поэтому происходит выборка ВСЕЙ(!) таблицы.
2. `RANK` проверяет на уникальность, поэтому нужно либо указывать все колонки, для того чтобы посчитать уникальный `RANK`(а подсчет `RANK` несомненно съедает не мало ресурсов на больших объемах таблицы), либо использовать `UNIQUE` колонки.

Comment: Этот способ работает, правда очень медленно. И вообще, адский 32-х битный интерфейс, за почти 40 лет устаревшей transbase, не оставляет лучшего выбора, кроме миграции на более современную SQL базу данных.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так: Берете первичный ключ из выборки, сделанной пользователем из таблицы, складываете его в промежуточную таблицу с IDENTITY и первичным ключом по IDENTITY, и для отображения страниц отдаете делаете запрос к промежуточной таблице с IDENTITY полем BETWEEN нужные значения, присоединяя основную таблицу по первичному ключу.

Comment: Насколько я Вас понял, такой вариант не очень подходит, поскольку он предполагает загрузки полной версии таблицы, а она может занимать гигабайты.

Comment: К тому, Transbase допускает поддержку *толстых* первичных ключей(multi-column), что еще также добавляет "распухания" SQL запросов на большом офсете для получения rows.

Comment: Почему полной? Только первичных ключей. Понятно, что это долго и тяжело, но других альтернатив, при отсутствии встроенной в движке возможности, я не вижу.

Comment: Возможно я Вас не правильно понял, и мне не совсем понятно, как к примеру мне с 100-го rows быстро перешагнуть к 100-тысячному? Опять крутить цикл курсором(Datareader-ом) и считать офсеты? Тогда это не очень понятное решения, с ненужным оверхедом, прочитанные ранее записи, я могу хранить и в DataTable, и это вообще не критично. Для меня было важней быстро перешагнуть на другой офсет, как это делается с Limit, а не быстрый доступ к ранее прочитанным rows. 
В общем, похоже нет другого способа, кроме как использовать курсоры в Transbase, это печально.

Comment: Какой цикл? Если вы в начале поместили все значения в пронумерованную таблицу, то при перемещении вы просто получаете из этой таблицы записи со 100.000 по 100.100.

Comment: К сожалению, я абсолютно не понимаю о чем Вы говорите, для меня это не имеет логического смысла. Если Вам не сложно, может объясните на примере, что Вы имеете ввиду?
У меня есть таблицы, с толстыми ключами(multiple columns), без auto increment, и эти таблицы, занимают гигабайты. Вы предлагаете, как я понял, получать для таблицы все первичные ключи, а в некоторых таблицах, они могут составлять 4-5 колонок(потому что multiple columns), и в итоге занимать гигабайты памяти.

Comment: Вот вы и выбирайте - что вам важнее - процессорное время, которое тратится на перебор курсора, либо память, которая тратится на сохранение выборки в промежуточную таблицу и нагрузка, которая создается при первичном заполнении промежуточной таблицы с identity. Идеальных вариантов тут нет - если движок не поддерживает этой возможности, вам придется идти на какие то издержки для ее реализации.

Comment: ну я это понимаю, и выбор в этом моменте, я сделал уже давно - лучше заплатить процессорным временем, чем такими объемами памяти. В любом случаи спасибо за Ваш совет.